# css rules multi class, how to match two out of many

Tags: css

A third party defined:

```
.c1 { ... }
```

I defined a rule to match both c1 and c2

```
.c1.c2 { ... }
```

For an element with **class="c1 c2"** my rule matches fine

However for an element with **class="c1 c2 [..other classes]"** my rule does not match and the third party's rule does.

How can I get my rule to match over the third party's rule in this case (without knowing in advance of the other classes and without changing the third party's rules) ?

Comment: Is there a common parent element? You could use that to extend your CSS's specificity.

Comment: A non-recommended kluj is to increase the specificity of your rule until it exceeds that of the third-party rule, by writing `.c1.c1.c1.c2.c2.c2`.

Comment: thx torazaburo ! that's great .. why 'non-recommended' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only **absolute** way to make sure your rule will take precedence over the others is to use the `!important` keyword:

```
.c1.c2 {
    color: red !important;
}
```

Note that if you know a more specific selector you can use it:

```css
.c1 {
  color: blue;
}
.c2 {
  color: pink;
}
.c1.c4 {
  color: pink !important;
}
.c1.c5 {
  color: white;
}
div .c1.c6 {
  color: gray;
}
.c1.c2 {
  color: red;
}
.c1.c3 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <div class="c1">blue due to .c1</div>
  <div class="c1 c2">red due to .c1.c2</div>
  <div class="c1 c2 c3">yellow due to .c1.c3</div>
  <div class="c1 c2 c3" style="color: black;">black due to inline style</div>
  <div class="c1 c2 c4">pink only because of the !important</div>
  <div class="c1 c2 c5">red becuase .c1.c2 is after .c1.c5 in the css</div>
  <div class="c1 c2 c6">gray only of more specific selector (div .c1.c5)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can set it inline :) (or find a more specific selector).

Comment: I'm in the middle of updating the answer with an example for that

Comment: @DrydenLong, you can check the update version. If you think I missed something you can say :)

Comment: Will appreciate if the downvoter will explain the reason for the downvote

Comment: Probably a knee-jerk reaction to `important`. By the way, to be extremely pedantic, the `!` is a delimiter and `important` is the keyword. Also, the word "absolute" is probably a bit strong. Another important declaration with greater specificity could override this in theory.

Answer (score 0):

if its specific to a single element you could also try using the id attribute as id defined css usurps classes.

```
#c1-override {
    color: red
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Syntax; When using multiple classnames for an set of CSS rules you need to seperate them with an comma.

```
.c1, .c2{
    /* CSS rules here */
}
```

You can also use declaration order instead of !important but its more organized to remove the rules from .c1 and .c2 which should be same.

Comment: This either misunderstands the question, or is the wrong answer to it.